# Excel VBA: Error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

This code is being used to enter a value in web form using Excel VBA:

```
Sub Call_Site(var1 As String)
Dim oHTML_Element As Object 'IHTMLElement
Dim sUrl As String

sUrl = "https://www.example.com/page"
Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.silent = True
'oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sUrl
oBrowser.Visible = False

With oBrowser
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: Loop
End With

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("nexcel")(0)

With HTMLDoc
   HTMLDoc.getElementById("var1").Value = var1
End With
Exit Sub
```

It happens that line:
       HTMLDoc.getElementById("var1").Value = var1

Is returning the error:

```
Error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method
```

Which only happens sometimes.

I can't understand why the error only happens sometimes (usually when it's critical) and what I can do to prevent it.

Having the browser visilble, it all seems normal.

Nowhere in similar answers I found a solution.

Comment: try this `HTMLDoc.getElementById("var1").Item(0).Value = var1`

Comment: Thanks, I get the same error though.

Comment: Is var1 an input element? If not, use `.innerText` not `.Value`.

Comment: It is a string (input by userform)

Comment: What type of HTML element are you trying to set `Value` on ?  Not all element types have a `Value` property to set.

Comment: It is an input field for a username, like <input name="username" id="var1" value="" class="validate-username required" size="25" required="" aria-required="true" autofocus="" type="text">

Comment: `oBrowser.document.getElementById("var1").Value` should work

Comment: @TimWilliams I tested it and it works. However, I don't uderstand why my code doesn't. Can you explain? Thank you.

Comment: You had set HTMLdoc to some other element before calling getElementbyid on it.  It's after to call it on the document object directly

Comment: @NunoNogueira what happens if you put `MsgBox TypeName(HTMLDoc)` right after setting it? If it's not "HTMLDocument", it would explain why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

use `oHTML_Element.Document.all.Item("var1").Value = var1`